# Parse HTML table to database format with PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing

I always had to show a table using the content of a database, but never backwards. One company just published a HTML table with some useful information, however they are not offering a database file, just the table.

It's a normal table. Just to clarify, something like:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>ELEMENT 1</td>
<td>ELEMENT2</td>
<td>ELEMENT 3</td>
<td>ELEMENT 4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is create a database with that date, being ELEMENT 1 the 'id', and the rest, information related with that id. I don't know how to create a bucle to get all the elements from that table, and insert them into the database.

What I'm asking is if there is a way to parse that information, so I can do what I want. I'm not asking the code to insert it into the database or so, just how should I parse that information. Thanks!

Comment: You can use javascript to access elements if they have `id`s and/or other info in their tags.

Comment: this is also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144061/using-php-to-get-dom-element

Comment: Hmm, maybe that DOMDocument thing could be useful in this case, thanks mavili!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
 <?php
  //Load the DOM Document
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");

  //Find td elements
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $query = '//your/path/to/table/tbody/tr/td';
  $entries = $xpath->query($query);

  $id = $entries->item(0);
  $item1 = $entries->item(1);
  $item2 = $entries->item(2);
  $item3 = $entries->item(3);

  //You query here...
 ?>
```

References:
[DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Thank you! I ended doing this: include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http:/...');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) 
{
...