# PHP if div contains word include page

Tags: php

I want to use PHP only, no jquery to include a page if a div contains the word YES. The reason for this is so that I can use CMS to change the content inside a div from YES to NO to include a page or not. I have tried preg_match, but it searches either a variable or exact phrase in the PHP itself. This is what I am looking for:

```
<div id="available">YES</div>

<?php if (preg_match("/YES/i", ID="available")) {
include 'page.php';
} else {
echo "Not Available.";
}
?>
```

I need the ID="available" to search the div id="available" and if YES is found, include the page, if not, echo "Not Available."   Thanks for any help.

Comment: `if a div contains the word YES` Where? In the same PHP file or as a string? Where is this div tag located ?

Comment: the div is one page1.php and I want to include page2.php if the div with the id="available" on page1.php contains the word YES.

Comment: the code in the question would all be located on the same page, page1.php

Comment: Can your CMS only change HTML? Why not just have the CMS change a variable in PHP (or better yet use a database or a text file to keep track).

Comment: Can't you do this using DOM?

Comment: CMS is third party, CushyCMS and it will not allow changing PHP

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8144104/5701450)

Comment: sorry, but having a brain fart. i see the DOM to get the getElementsByTagName for the div id="available", how would I use that to search it for the word YES and then include the php page?

Comment: if you cant change the php, how can this ever work?

Comment: If would have to be done with Ajax on a custom php file and overwrite the div on the fly. Personally I would prefer to go the opensource route and eliminate the need to hack together something like this.

Comment: @ nogad - i can change the PHP in the code, just not the CMS. CMS is for HTML only, that is why I am looking at the PHP searchng at the div content instead of a variable.

Comment: One question, where does the **YES** come from? is it hardcoded in the `page1.php` or it's a variable? I think if it's not hardcoded and you are on the fame file, then you can check the content of that variable!

Comment: YES is the text content inside of the div.

Comment: I can see that, But what I'm asking is where does it come from?!

Comment: Let me clarify, when you edit your `page1.php`, You have exactly `<div id="available">YES</div>` or you have something like this: `<div id="available">$someVariable</div>`. If you have case 1, it means that you always have **YES** in your div what so ever! if you have case 2, then you can check `$someVariable` to see if it contains **YES** or not!

Comment: @EhsanT - it is case1, <div id="available">YES</div> which can be changed with CMS to say YES or NO. If YES, I want it to include page2.php

Comment: So you are telling CMS actually edits `page1.php` and changes the content of it and saves it on the server?! and then you have some other code in the same `page1.php` which you want that code check the specific content of the same file for a value and do or do not  do something base on that value?

Comment: @EhsanT - yes, the value of the div content

Comment: Although I hardly can imagine a CMS would do that, But if that's the case, your best choice is using [php DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [php DOMXpath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This will allow you to edit your PHP variable with cushycms to include a page. If the div id="available" is anything other than Yes, the page2.php will not be included on page1.php. The code is attached below.

Page1.php

```
<h1>This is Page1.php </h1>
<?php
// locate page you want to check div on - page2.php
$content = file_get_contents('page2.php');
// input your specific div id from - page2.php
$first_step = explode( '<div id="available">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</div>" , $first_step[1] );
// name your variable - in this case - $available
$available = trim($second_step[0]);
// input your output variable - $available and word to match in div - 'Yes'
if(false !== stripos($available, 'Yes')){
// if word in div=id'available' on page2.php is Yes - include page or echo
include 'page2.php';
}
?>
```

Note: on page2.php for this and cushycms to work, you have to put the div id="available" inside another div to have classes or styles  - see example below

Page2.php

```
<div id="wrapper" class="cushycms">
<div id="available">Yes</div>
</div>
<h2>Please include this rental into the page</h2>
```