# PHP save inner html of p tag, only 1 p tag on page

Tags: php

I am trying to get the inner html of a `<p>` tag and save it as a .txt file. It is a very simple page; there is only one `<p>` on it. I tried using `getElementsByTagName('p')` as per: [Using PHP to get DOM Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144061/using-php-to-get-dom-element). Unfortunately, it didn't work for me, but maybe I'm missing something. My code is:

```php
<?php
$dataPage = file_get_contents('http://www.somedataurl.com');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($dataPage);

$dataNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
$dataNode = $dataNodeList->item(0);

function innerHTML($node) {
    return implode(array_map([$node->ownerDocument, "saveHTML"],
            iterator_to_array($node->childNodes)));
}

$theData = innerHTML($dataNode);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$filename = date('Y-m-d') . '.txt';
file_put_contents($filename, $theData);
```

The error log is giving me:

> PHP Notice: Undefined property:: DOMNodeList (line 10)
>
> PHP Notice: Undefined property:: DOMNodeList (line 11)
>
> PHP Catchable fatal error (line 11)

These errors sound rather alarming, especially the last one.

**Question:** Is there a better tool I can use other than `getElementsByTagName()` since I am only dealing with one `<p>`? Or can this way work if I adjust a few things?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your script finds any `<p>` tags?

Comment: To directly answer your question; I'd say you're using the most efficient method right now.

Comment: @Phil I know the `<p>` tags are there, but judging by "Undefined property" I think my script might not be finding them for some reason. My only other hunch was a data structure error, domnodelist vs node

Comment: How about doing some simple debugging? Eg `var_dump($dataNodeList->length)` or even `var_dump($doc->saveHTML())` to make sure you're getting the document you expect

Comment: @Phil Its on a remote server and I have to use cron to run it. My IDE doesn't run PHP, debug learning curve is tough on cron. I typically can only tell if it works if a txt file is created or not. I have had it working in the past using `xpath` for finding elements by class name, but this new page only has a `<p>` with no class.

Comment: So write to the error log ~ http://php.net/manual/function.error-log.php

Comment: Also, try running it locally in a docker container or VM or something. It's quite easy these days to get a local PHP development environment up and running

Comment: How about even just using `curl` or Postman to check the HTML returned. Make sure the `<p>` tag you think is there isn't coming from JavaScript

Comment: @Phil Well you won't believe this, but, as per your suggestion, when I added `error_log($dataNodeList->length, 0);` it worked, seemingly out of the blue. Text file created with the data. Error log read: 1, meaning the list had found the p. So weird.

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one P tag,i think you had better extract P content using Regular Expressions

example:

```
preg_match("/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/is",$dataPage,$match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Comment: That's assuming the `<p>` tag doesn't have any attributes and there's no newlines between the `<` and `>` characters of each opening and closing tag. Then there's this ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/283366

Comment: Also, OP's code should work just fine if there is in fact a `<p>` tag in the document